# How to perform inner join on array and table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array of hash, which stores data from api. How can I perform `inner join` on it with a table.

```
> posts
[{ uuid: 'post1', user_uuid: 'user1' },
 { uuid: 'post2', user_uuid: 'user2' }]

> User.all
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, uuid: "user1", name: "User1">]>
```

I expect to get an array like

```
[{ uuid: 'post1', user_uuid: 'user1', user_name: 'User1' }]
```

`user2` does not exist in table, so it will not be in the result array.

Answer (score 1):

this is sample for you code above **not inner join** since the other table (posts) is not relational table in database

```
arr1 = Array.new
users = User.all
users.each do |user|
 post = posts.detect { |d| d[:user_uuid] == user.uuid }
 # detect will check if here is matching between user and posts content
 arr1 << {uuid: post[:uuid], user_uuid: post[:user_uuid], user_name: user.name} if post.present?
end
puts arr1
```